# Multiple mutable borrows during a depth-first tree search

Tags: rust

How would one restructure this function that does a depth-first search and returns the parent of the matching node?

I know that variations of this problem have come up very often (e.g. [Multiple mutable borrows when generating a tree structure with a recursive function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563762/multiple-mutable-borrows-when-generating-a-tree-structure-with-a-recursive-funct), [Mut borrow not ending where expected](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2wggjb/mutable_borrow_not_ending_where_expected/)), but I still can’t figure out how to modify it to work. I have tried variations using slices, `std::mem::drop`, and adding lifetime parameters `where 'a: 'b` but I still haven’t figured out write it without conditionally mutably borrowing a variable in one branch and then using the variable in another branch.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct TreeNode {
    id: i32,
    children: Vec<TreeNode>,
}

// Returns a mutable reference to the parent of the node that matches the given id.
fn find_parent_mut<'a>(root: &'a mut TreeNode, id: i32) -> Option<&'a mut TreeNode> {
    for child in root.children.iter_mut() {
        if child.id == id {
            return Some(root);
        } else {
            let descendent_result = find_parent_mut(child, id);
            if descendent_result.is_some() {
                return descendent_result;
            }
        }
    }
    None
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = TreeNode {
        id: 1,
        children: vec![TreeNode {
                           id: 2,
                           children: vec![TreeNode {
                                              id: 3,
                                              children: vec![],
                                          }],
                       }],
    };
    let a: Option<&mut TreeNode> = find_parent_mut(&mut tree, 3);
    assert_eq!(a.unwrap().id, 2);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*root` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
9  |     for child in root.children.iter_mut() {
   |                  ------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |         if child.id == id {
11 |             return Some(root);
   |                         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
20 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Here it is with @huon’s suggestions and continued compiler errors:

```
fn find_parent_mut<'a>(root: &'a mut TreeNode, id: i32) -> Option<&'a mut TreeNode> {
    for child in root.children {
        if child.id == id {
            return Some(root);
        }
    }
    for i in 0..root.children.len() {
        let child: &'a mut TreeNode = &mut root.children[i];
        let descendent_result = find_parent_mut(child, id);
        if descendent_result.is_some() {
            return descendent_result;
        }
    }
    None
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |     for child in root.children {
  |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `root.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:15:44
   |
15 |         let child: &'a mut TreeNode = &mut root.children[i];
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                            |
   |                                            second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                            first mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to have it working this way:

```rust
fn find_parent_mut<'a>(root: &'a mut TreeNode, id: i32)
        -> Option<&'a mut TreeNode> {
    if root.children.iter().any(|child| {child.id == id}) {
        return Some(root); 
    }
    for child in &mut root.children {
        match find_parent_mut(child, id) {
            Some(result) => return Some(result),
            None => {}
        }
    }
    None
}
```

First in you second attempt, you wrote `for child in root.children` instead of the `for child in &mut root.children` (note the missing `&mut`),which caused root.children to be consumed by the loop instead of just iterated over, hence the `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

I also folded it in a more iterator-ich way, using the [`any(..)`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) function.

For the second loop, I'm not exactly sure what was going on, by apparently binding the references to variables was confusing the borrow-checker. I removed any temporary variable, and now it compiles.

Comment: NB. this unfortunately does two loops over the array.

Answer (score 2):

One can do this in a single pass by doing the search, recording some data from it, and then computing the return value efficiently outside the loop:

```
let mut found = Err(());
for (i, child) in root.children.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    if child.id == id {
        found = Ok(None);
        break;
    }  else find_parent_mut(child, id).is_some() {
        found = Ok(Some(i));
        break;
    }
}
match found {
    Ok(Some(i)) => Some(&mut root.children[i]),
    Ok(None) => Some(root),
    Err(()) => None,
}
```

This avoids the issues caused by conditionally returning mutable variables (which is the problems you and my answer below were meeting) by completely avoiding returns inside the inner loop.

---

Old/incorrect answer:

I'm unable to test my suggestions right now, but I believe the best way to solve this is to return `root` outside the loop.

```
for child in &mut root.children {
    if child.id == id {
        found = true;
        break
    } ...
}
if found {
    Some(root)
} else {
    None
}
```

This (hopefully) ensures that `root` isn't borrowed via `children` when it is being manipulated.

However I suspect the early return inside the main loop may interfere, in which case one might just have to fall back to integers and indexing:

```
for i in 0..root.children.len() {
    if root.children[i].id == id {
        return Some(root)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Separating the loops and using indexing doesn’t seem to have worked.

Comment: @yonran, you misinterpretered slightly: I wasn't suggesting to do two separate loops, but you are correct that my original suggestion doesn't solve the fundamental issue. I've now been able to test properly, and edited in a new version that does work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why `for child in root.children.iter_mut()` borrows `root.children` forever if there is a `return` inside, but is fine when you use a local variable instead?

Comment: This formulation is not correct. Consider the simple linear tree 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 as input (where 1 is the root, and each node has just one child). `find_parent_mut(root, 4)` will return the `2` node for this tree, when the correct result would be the `3` node. Basically, this function will never return a result more than one level deep in the tree.